# How to get Ubuntu back alongside Windows as operating systems?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, bios, operating-systems

I initially had both Windows 10 Home and Ubuntu installed as operating systems on my PC. When I have opened the PC, it displayed me a purple display where it was to choose between Ubuntu and Windows. After, I update the Windows to Windows 10 Pro. Also, I entered on BIOS, but I haven't done anything. Maybe the update changed something? Now, I cannot acces Ubuntu! Is like I don't have it, it isn't any choice option for me to choose between them two and the PC starts with Windows. However, when I enter on BIOS it shows me that I have both Ubuntu and Windows, but Windows is the first. I tried to change the ordered, but it is not possible. After long searches on the Internet, I found out that it may be possible to repair this by switching between the UEFIs, but I only found one UEFI... Also, I disabled the secure boot. Does anyone know how to manage this problem and how to get back at having both Ubuntu and Windows choices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The purple screen you are referring to is GRUB. Windows will overwrite GRUB whenever you upgrade, as you are experiencing.

'How do i prevent windows upgrades from overwriting grub in a dual boot scenario; how do i restore grub after windows upgrade' is what i think you're trying to answer

Try looking at both of these questions and answers [here from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

and [here from stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine)

There should be enough information to get back to the desired behavior